# Get the error line with my code on ELMAH

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

I have set up ELMAH on my Asp.Net MVC 5 website. It's working fine but its error details page is not showing me the exact line that's causing the exception. I was wondering whether I could get the same error page as the default Asp.Net error on my local machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you deploy the PDB files corresponding to the DLLs in your web application's or site's `bin` directory then the stack trace in the error will contain line information as well.

Comment: So did you get a chance to try it out and did it work?

Comment: Hi. Sorry I forgot to update this. Yes, I uploaded the PDB files and it definitely changed the error logs but it's still not the same as the ones I get when I use my machine. In my dev machine, I can see exactly which line is causing the error and it has a red text. Can I achieve the same with ELMAH?

Comment: @AlirezaNoori I'm afraid not. ELMAH usually does not have access to source code in production so that's not a scenario that really needed addressing. Next best you can get is the [YSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_of_death) from ASP.NET for pages & controls that ELMAH does capture if available.

Comment: The YSOD is exactly what I'm looking for but I don't want the clients to see it. That's why I use ELMAH and use custom error reporting to the users.